Fluentd Not able to format json to customized output
Below is the json output which we recieve in Fluentd from OTEL Collector
"tags": [
    {
            "key": "otel.library.name",
            "vStr": "com.mgmt.Typedcons"
        },
        {
            "key": "ta.work.status",
            "vStr": "COMPLETED"
        },
        {
            "key": "ta.work.receivedTime",
            "vType": "INT64",
            "vInt64": "1721644532158"
        }
    ]

Tried using json multi line format & json flatten_hash plugin
Tried using json flatten_hash plugin as below which didn't work
Need to output to Elastic search in proper fields format. Json expecting to be as below:
{"tag.otel@library@name": "com.mgmt.Typedcons", "tag.ta@work@status": "COMPLETED", "tag.ta@work@receivedTime": "1721644532158"}

your input isn't accurately a json object. you'll need the whole thing in {} to have valid json

also it could be better if you explain how you want to change your records, instead of a sample input/output. e.g., do you completely ignore vType?

you can use enable_ruby true to format your logs very conveniently.
try a fluentd filter like this:
<filter myapp.logs>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    transformed_tags "#{record['tags'].map { |tag| ['tag.' + tag['key'].gsub('.', '@'), tag['vStr'] || tag['vInt64']].to_h }.reduce({}, :merge)}"
  </record>
</filter>

explanation:

access the tag key of each record
map each tag to the following:

start the value of key with tag.
replace every . with an @
pick vType or vInt64, whichever is present
finally merge them all together



